# how to do 3d sum using openmp

Tags: sum, openmp

I am a freshman in openmp. I have some trouble in a 3d sum, and I don't know how to improve my code. Here's the code I want to improve in openmp. My aim is to speed up the calculation of this 3d sum. What should I add in my code according to the rules of openmp?
I add #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:integral) in my code. But an error happens which says the initialization of 'for' is not correct. This is the information of this error:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWhgB.png) I am a chinese, so the language of my IDE is chinese. I use Visual Studio 2019.

```
 #include<omp.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
    double a = 0.3291;
    double d_title = 2.414;
    double b = 3.8037;
    double c = 4086;
    double nu_start = 0;
    double mu_start = 0;
    double z_start = 0;
    double step_nu = 2 * 3.1415926 / 100;
    double step_mu = 3.1415926 / 100;
    double step_z = 0;
    double nu = 0;
    double mu = 0;
    double z = 0;
    double integral=0;
    double d_uv = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(a, d_title, b, c, nu_start, mu_start, z_start, step_nu, step_mu) private( j,k,mu, nu, step_z, z, d_uv) reduction(+:integral)
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        mu = mu_start + (i + 1) * step_mu;
        for (j = 0; j < 100; j++)
        {
            
            nu = nu_start + (j + 1) * step_nu;
            for (k = 0; k < 500; k++)
            {
                d_uv = (sin(mu) * sin(mu) * cos(nu) * cos(nu) + sin(mu) * sin(mu) * (a * sin(nu) - d_title * cos(nu)) * (a * sin(nu) - d_title * cos(nu)) + b * b * cos(mu) * cos(mu)) / (c * c);
                step_z = 20 / (d_uv * 500);
                z = z_start + (k + 1) * step_z;
                
                integral = integral + sin(mu) * (1 - 3 * sin(mu) * sin(mu) * cos(nu) * cos(nu)) * exp(-d_uv * z) * log(1 + z * z) * step_z * step_mu * step_nu;
            }

        }

    }

    double out = 0;
    out = integral / (c * c);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solutions (UPDATE: It is an answer to the original question:)

1. To do the least typing you just have to add the following line before `for(int i=..)`

`#pragma omp parallel for private( mu, nu, step_z, z, d_uv) reduction(+:integral)`

Here you define which variables have to be private to avoid data race. Note that variables are shared by default, so variable `integral` also shared, but all threads update its value, which is a data race. To avoid it, you have 2 possibilities: use atomic operation, or a much better option is to use use reduction (add `reduction(+:integral)` clause).

2. As you mentioned that you are beginner in OpenMP it is recommended to use `default(none)` clause in the `#pragma omp parallel for` directive, so you have to explicitly define sharing attributes. If you forget a variable you will get an error, so you have to consider all variables involved in your parallel region and can think about possible data races:

`#pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(a, d_title, b, c, nu_start, mu_start, z_start, step_nu, step_mu) private( mu, nu, step_z, z, d_uv) reduction(+:integral)`

3. Generally, it is recommended to define your variables in their minimum required scope, so variables defined inside the `for` loop to parallelize will be private. In this case you just have to add `#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:integral)` before your outermost `for` loop, so your code will be:

```
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:integral)
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        double mu = mu_start + (i + 1) * step_mu;
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
        {
            //int id = omp_get_thread_num();
            double nu = nu_start + (j + 1) * step_nu;
            for (int k = 0; k < 500; k++)
            {
                double d_uv = (sin(mu) * sin(mu) * cos(nu) * cos(nu) + sin(mu) * sin(mu) * (a * sin(nu) - d_title * cos(nu)) * (a * sin(nu) - d_title * cos(nu)) + b * b * cos(mu) * cos(mu)) / (c * c);
                double step_z = 20 / (d_uv * 500);
                double z = z_start + (k + 1) * step_z;
                //int id = omp_get_thread_num();
                integral = integral + sin(mu) * (1 - 3 * sin(mu) * sin(mu) * cos(nu) * cos(nu)) * exp(-d_uv * z) * log(1 + z * z) * step_z * step_mu * step_nu;
            }

        }

    }
```

Runtimes: 44 ms (1 thread) and 11 ms (4 threads) on my computer (g++ -O3 -mavx2 -fopenmp).

Comment: I tried your advice. But an error happened which says the initialization of 'for' is not correct. Please kindly show me how to cope with it.

Comment: You probably mistyped something, here is the CodeExplorer link: https://godbolt.org/z/hGfa47dWz

Comment: I define i,j and k in advance, set j and k as private, and replace int i ,int j, int k by i,j,k in the 'for' sentence. Then there's no error. Could you tell me the reason? I've updated my code.

Comment: Variable `i` is privatized by the OpenMP standard, so you do not have to set it private.

Comment: Your updated code works on CompilerExplorer, so it must be some problem with your compiler.

Comment: Do not forget to upvote (and accept) answer if you find it useful.