# speed performance using openmp in a sub-funciton

Tags: c, openmp

I use openmp in a function and then this function is called in the main function, but I find this is much slower than directly putting everything in the main function. I'd like to know the reason and methods to solve it.
Code 1:

```
#include<omp.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
double func()
{
    double a[500];
    double d_title[500];
    double b[500];
    double c[500];
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        a[i] = 0.3291;
        d_title[i] = 2.414;
        b[i] = 3.8037;
        c[i] = 4086;
    }
    double nu_start = 0;
    double mu_start = 0;
    double z_start = 0;
    double step_nu = 2 * 3.1415926 / 100;
    double step_mu = 3.1415926 / 100;
    double step_z = 0;
    double nu = 0;
    double mu = 0;
    double z = 0;
    double integral = 0;
    double d_uv = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int loop = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(a, d_title, b, c, nu_start, mu_start, z_start, step_nu, step_mu) private( i,j,k,mu, nu, step_z, z, d_uv)
    for (loop = 0; loop < 500; loop++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            mu = mu_start + (i + 1) * step_mu;
            for (j = 0; j < 100; j++)
            {

                nu = nu_start + (j + 1) * step_nu;
                for (k = 0; k < 500; k++)
                {
                    d_uv = (sin(mu) * sin(mu) * cos(nu) * cos(nu) + sin(mu) * sin(mu) * (a[loop] * sin(nu) - d_title[loop] * cos(nu)) * (a[loop] * sin(nu) - d_title[loop] * cos(nu)) + b[loop] * b[loop] * cos(mu) * cos(mu)) / (c[loop] * c[loop]);
                    step_z = 20 / (d_uv * 500);
                    z = z_start + (k + 1) * step_z;
                    #pragma omp atomic
                    integral +=sin(mu) * (1 - 3 * sin(mu) * sin(mu) * cos(nu) * cos(nu)) * exp(-d_uv * z) * log(1 + z * z) * step_z * step_mu * step_nu / (c[loop] * c[loop]);
                }

            }

        }
    }


    return integral;
}

int main() 
{
    double a;
    a = func();
    return 0;
}
```

Code 2:

```
Everything is the same except put the content of the function 'func' in the main function.
```

code 1 is much slower than code2.

Comment: I guess it is related to compiler optimization. It is hard to tell for sure. Do you still have performance issues if you declare func to be inline, or if you increase the level of optimization ?

Comment: Which compiler and compiler flags do you use? 
Unrelated question: Why do you use atomic operation instead of reduction?

Comment: Could you please run these two codes on your computer and see if the same thing happens to you

Comment: I use the default compiler in Visual Studio 2019

Comment: For starters, try cleaning up your code by declaring your variables only in the scope where you are using them. You prevented most compiler optimizations from happening at all otherwise. Only from there on you can even start to reduce it to a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Ext3h I have already suggested the OP to use the the variables in their minimal required scope https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69836096/how-to-do-3d-sum-using-openmp

Comment: @zhuruihu I got exactly the same speed. Note that to compile your code `integral` should be listed among the shared variables.

Answer (score 1):

Why it's faster if you fused everything into `main()`?

Because you then discarded the result in the same function, and the compiler was allowed to also eliminate *everything* which had only been required to get to the required result.

The entire calculation was simply eliminated beginning from the (no longer required) result. As long as there are no observable side effects, the compiler may just do that.

The function boundary (and the function not being declared `inline` or  `static` visibility) results in the compiler being required to assume that someone other than `main()` might require the result after all, so it can't trim down the body of `func()`.

So if you want to measure correctly, observe your result! Just a simple `printf()` will make all the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Even if your application did not optimize away when everything was in main(), there are still simple improvements you can make to improve the performance of your code. Your function and my improved version (in calculate.c):

```
#include "calculate.h"

#include <omp.h>
#include <math.h>

#define DATA_SIZE 500
#define NUMBER_OF_STEPS 100

static double a[DATA_SIZE];
static double d_title[DATA_SIZE];
static double b[DATA_SIZE];
static double c[DATA_SIZE];

void initialize_data()
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < DATA_SIZE; i++)
    {
        a[i] = 0.3291;
        d_title[i] = 2.414;
        b[i] = 3.8037;
        c[i] = 4086;
    }
}

double func()
{
    double nu_start = 0;
    double mu_start = 0;
    double z_start = 0;
    double step_nu = 2 * M_PI / NUMBER_OF_STEPS;
    double step_mu = M_PI / NUMBER_OF_STEPS;
    double step_z = 0;
    double nu = 0;
    double mu = 0;
    double z = 0;
    double integral = 0;
    double d_uv = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int loop = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(a, d_title, b, c, nu_start, mu_start, z_start, step_nu, step_mu, integral) private(i, j, k, mu, nu, step_z, z, d_uv)
    for (loop = 0; loop < DATA_SIZE; loop++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_STEPS; i++)
        {
            mu = mu_start + (i + 1) * step_mu;
            for (j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_STEPS; j++)
            {

                nu = nu_start + (j + 1) * step_nu;
                for (k = 0; k < DATA_SIZE; k++)
                {
                    d_uv = (sin(mu) * sin(mu) * cos(nu) * cos(nu) + sin(mu) * sin(mu) * (a[loop] * sin(nu) - d_title[loop] * cos(nu)) * (a[loop] * sin(nu) - d_title[loop] * cos(nu)) + b[loop] * b[loop] * cos(mu) * cos(mu)) / (c[loop] * c[loop]);
                    step_z = 20 / (d_uv * DATA_SIZE);
                    z = z_start + (k + 1) * step_z;
#pragma omp atomic
                    integral += sin(mu) * (1 - 3 * sin(mu) * sin(mu) * cos(nu) * cos(nu)) * exp(-d_uv * z) * log(1 + z * z) * step_z * step_mu * step_nu / (c[loop] * c[loop]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return integral;
}

double func2()
{
    double integral = 0;
    int loop = 0;
    int i = 0;

#pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(a, d_title, b, c) reduction(+: integral) collapse(2)
    for (loop = 0; loop < DATA_SIZE; loop++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_STEPS; i++)
        {
            const double mu_start = 0;
            const double step_mu = M_PI / NUMBER_OF_STEPS;
            const double mu = mu_start + (i + 1) * step_mu;

            int j;
            for (j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_STEPS; j++)
            {
                const double nu_start = 0;
                const double step_nu = 2 * M_PI / NUMBER_OF_STEPS;
                const double nu = nu_start + (j + 1) * step_nu;

                int k;
                for (k = 0; k < DATA_SIZE; k++)
                {
                    const double z_start = 0;
                    const double d_uv = (sin(mu) * sin(mu) * cos(nu) * cos(nu) + sin(mu) * sin(mu) * (a[loop] * sin(nu) - d_title[loop] * cos(nu)) * (a[loop] * sin(nu) - d_title[loop] * cos(nu)) + b[loop] * b[loop] * cos(mu) * cos(mu)) / (c[loop] * c[loop]);
                    const double step_z = 20 / (d_uv * DATA_SIZE);
                    const double z = z_start + (k + 1) * step_z;

                    integral += sin(mu) * (1 - 3 * sin(mu) * sin(mu) * cos(nu) * cos(nu)) * exp(-d_uv * z) * log(1 + z * z) * step_z * step_mu * step_nu / (c[loop] * c[loop]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return integral;
}
```

The header (calculate.h):

```
#ifndef CALCULATE_H
#define CALCULATE_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

    void initialize_data();
    double func();
    double func2();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif


#endif
```

The main application (openmp-performance.cpp) which uses [Google Benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark):

```
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>
#include "calculate.h"

static void BM_original_func(benchmark::State& state)
{
    initialize_data();

    for (auto _ : state) 
    {
        const double result = func();

        state.counters["result"] = result;
    }
}

static void BM_func2(benchmark::State& state)
{
    initialize_data();

    for (auto _ : state)
    {
        const double result = func2();

        state.counters["result"] = result;
    }
}

BENCHMARK(BM_original_func)->Unit(benchmark::kSecond);
BENCHMARK(BM_func2)->Unit(benchmark::kSecond);
BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

I built with a Makefile:

```
CXXFLAGS+=-Wall -march=native -g -fopenmp -O2
CFLAGS=$(CXXFLAGS)
LDFLAGS=-lpthread -lbenchmark

TARGET = benchmark

all : $(TARGET)

$(TARGET) : calculate.o openmp-performance.o
        g++ $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

.PHONY : clean
clean :
        rm -f $(TARGET) *.o
```

I built and executed the code on a Linux machine but you should get similar results:

```
[dan@cpp-slave openmp-performance]$ make && ./benchmark
cc -Wall -march=native -g -fopenmp -O2   -c -o calculate.o calculate.c
g++ -Wall -march=native -g -fopenmp -O2   -c -o openmp-performance.o openmp-performance.cpp
g++ -Wall -march=native -g -fopenmp -O2 calculate.o openmp-performance.o -o benchmark -lpthread -lbenchmark
2021-11-12T16:13:01+01:00
Running ./benchmark
Run on (4 X 2394 MHz CPU s)
CPU Caches:
  L1 Data 32 KiB (x4)
  L1 Instruction 32 KiB (x4)
  L2 Unified 4096 KiB (x4)
  L3 Unified 16384 KiB (x1)
Load Average: 0.58, 0.52, 0.59
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                 Time             CPU   Iterations UserCounters...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
BM_original_func        104 s           102 s             1 result=46.2432k
BM_func2               27.8 s          26.7 s             1 result=46.2432k
```

Just by changing the OpenMP declarations a little and pushing variables down a bit, I was able to significantly improve the performance of your function:

1. Replacing an atomic with a reduction made a big difference.

   1. Using an atomic operation causes all additions from multiple threads to be serialized.
   2. Using a reduction here sums the subtotals from the individual threads at the end.
2. Pre-calculating sin(mu) and cos(nu) made no difference at all which suggests the compiler spotted the optimization for itself.